# Proxy an Observable and connect it in callback

Tags: rxjs, observable, subscription, subject-observer

I'm trying to return an `Observable` that is created asynchronously in a callback:

```js
const mkAsync = (observer, delay) =>
  setTimeout(() => Observable.of('some result').subscribe(observer), delay)

const create = arg => {
  const ret = new Subject()
  mkAsync(ret, arg)
  return ret
}
```

Therefore I use a `Subject` as a unicast proxy which is subscribed to the underlying `Observable` in the callback.

The problem I have with this solution is that when I unsubscribe from the `Subject`'s subsrciption the unsubscribe isn't forwarded to the underlying `Observable`. Looks like I need some type of refcounting to make the `Subject` unsubscribe when there are no more subscribers, but I wasn't able to figure it out when using it in this kind of imperative callback style.

I have to keep the `mkAsync` a void and am looking for an alternative implementation.

Is that the right way to do it? Is there an alternative solution to using a `Subject`?

How do I make sure that the created `Observable` is cancelled (`unsubscribe` is called on the `Subscription`) when the Subject is unsubscribed from?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty broad question and it's hard to tell what are you trying to achieve with this. I have two ideas:

The first thing is that there is `refCount()` operator that exists only on `ConnectableObservable` class that is returned from `multicast` (or `publish`) depending on the parameters you pass. See implementation for more details (basically if you don't set any `selector` function): https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.11/src/operators/multicast.ts

The second issue I can think of is that you're doing basically this:

```
const ret = new Subject()
Observable.of(...).subscribe(ret);
```

The problem with this is that `.of` will emit immediately it's `next` items and then it sends the `complete` notification. Subjects have internal state and when `Subject` receives the `complete` notification it marks itself as `stopped` and **it will never ever emit anything**.

I'm suspicious that's what's happening to you. Even when you return the Subject instance with `return ret` and later probably subscribe to it you still won't receive anything because this Subject has already received the `complete` notification.

Comment: As it seems `refCount` gives me a new Observable but I already return the Subject. The current approach basically works, safe for the unsubscribe issue. I could use a ReplaySubject to not miss any events but for now I instantly subscribe to the Subject.